# CSV file column data with comma separated is displaying as number when opened in excel (JAVA)

Tags: java, excel, csv, formatting

Created csv file with name text.csv (Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv) type) with column data in the column as 55,666,666,7777,9999,7777,999,777 through java code. If I try to open the file by 5.56666667777999E+25. Even by changing the format of the cell, the data is displaying in the same format. But if I use Text Import Wizard and selecting the Column data format as 'Text' I am able to see the data in the way I created while writing the CSV file.

Is that something I can do through code, or is this related to Excel formatting. As when we provide the same to client, they won't change the formatter the column in excel. They just double click and open the file.

Comment: Excel formatting. Use a text editor to open the file or add a `'` before the number to let Excel know that it is a text. That usually works.

Comment: can you change the The excel format column for text?, also you can use in the  java program a bigdecimal

Comment: Thank you, opening with text editor is working.